# Не обновляются данные на web-странице flask

Tags: python, jquery, flask

Я хочу с помощью random отображать число на web-странице и при get запросе обновлять число полученное при помощи random
вот такой код у меня есть:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from random import randint

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def temperature():
    rand = randint(0, 9)
    s = render_template('home.html', rands = rand)
    print(rand)
    print(s)
    return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

home.html выглядит так:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Temperature</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id ="temperature">

 </div>
 <script>
 function NewData(){
   $.get("/", function(data, status){
    $("#temperature").text({{rands}});
    })
   }

 setInterval(() => NewData(), 20000);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

При перезагрузке страницы вручную (нажав F5) в {{rands}} записывается новое рандомное значение, но когда работает скрипт и происходит get запрос через скрипт, то полученное значение числа всегда одно и тоже.

Хотя в консольном выводе при каждом get запросе выводится новое рандомное число, а на web-сайте всегда статичное число полученное при первом запуске web-страницы.

вот пример, всегда статичное число, полученное при первой загрузке web-страницы = 9
[image: web-страница]
первый вывод в консоль, получаем значение = 9
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
второй вывод в консоль значение уже = 0, но на веб странице по прежнему = 9
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В этом ничего удивительного. Вы же генерируете случайное число один раз при загрузке страницы. Далее при вызове функции `NewData` она всегда использует то же самое число, так вы его прописали как константу в html странице.

Нужно чтоб `NewData` использовала результат запроса на сервер, а не константу:

```
 function NewData(){
   $.get("/temp", function(data, status){
    $("#temperature").text(data.value);
    })
   }
```

А на сервере нужно создать endpoint, который будет возвращать данные для `NewData`:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    s = render_template('home.html')
    return s

@app.route('/temp')
def temperature():
    rand = randint(0, 9)
    return {'value': rand}
```

Или вариант с одним endpoint:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    if request.args.get('rand', 'false') == 'true':
        rand = randint(0, 9)
        return {'value': rand}
    else:
        s = render_template('home.html')
        return s

...
   $.get("/?rand=true", function(data, status){
    $("#temperature").text(data.value);
    })
   }
```

Comment: Есть ли возможность реализовать без использования дополнительного роута?

Comment: Можно передавать параметр в существующий и возвращать значение в зависимости от того передали его или нет.